# Waiting for a background operation to complete

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, razor, freeze

I have been suffering from the all too common 'Waiting for a background operation to complete...' message in Visual Studio 2012 (Professional) for a while now but it has been fairly sporadic.

Lately though, I am really struggling to use Visual Studio as pretty much whenever i try and do anything with any Razor views (mostly clicking to move the cursor) visual studio hangs and the above message appears for about a minute at a time.
(If when its finished doing stuff i then click in the view again, the process repeats, and repeats, and repeats.....)

I have searched high and low, and read loads of articles regarding this and peoples suggestions and tried changing indentation settings, resetting settings, etc but none have worked.

Has anyone come across something else that may work as this is seriously impeding my ability to use visual studio and sadly provoking much cursing.

Comment: Is your project on your local disk or a network share?  Have you installed VS 2012 Update 2, it may have some bug fixes that may help?

Comment: Yup, Update 2 is installed and as far as im aware all aspect of Visual Studio 2012 are up to date. And yes the project is hosted on a network share for backup and shadow copy purposes. However, I have no issues with any parts of my project other that the razor pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I asked this question a while back, but I thought best to put up my findings as they may help others.

The exact reason for the Waiting dialog is still unknown, but I have since moved my project to a local disk and implemented Team Foundation server to perform the hosting and backup of the main project files.

Since moving to local disk and using TFS, I have not experienced any more of the VS Waiting dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue with VS2012 and unfortunately I had to format my pc after trying all the following solutions:

1. Move/clean the symbols cache
2. Reset VS preferences
3. Install Upgrade 2
4. Uninstall/Reinstall VS

After formatting and reinstalling VS2012, it started working like a charm again (obviously).

Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Check if IIS or another process (BizTalk maybe) is locking your DLLs/references

Kill/stop IIS if it is